# ios loadNibNamed to Superclass

Tags: ios, inheritance, xib, nib, superclass

I have got a view.xib file with a CustomClass = "BaseClass" (I configure it on XCode editor), so I can do that:

```
BaseClass *mBassClass= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"view" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But I want to know how I can do that:

I would have got a child class from BaseClass. For example ChildClass extends from BaseClass, and load a view from Nib but with a ChildClass

```
ChildClass *aChild = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"view" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

ChildClass2 *anotherView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"view" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

So, I want to have got BaseClass with some child class with specific functions but all of these views have got the same Nib file

In **my case** I'm developing the following views:

**(1)** A nib file, it has got some uibutton from control and a UIView that will contain a Core Plot Graph

**(2)** A BaseClass, called GraphView, it matchs with the nib file and it does function with the uibuttons.

**(3)** Some child class, each one paint a different graph/plot on the UIView, but the inherits the functions of uibutton controls.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the question asking about what you want to achieve with the app / views, not asking about abstract classes and views (because I don't understand what you're asking currently)

Comment: done, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I know that a solution could be: separate the logic from the view. So, only I got a BaseClass and inside I declare a some Control Class var, this control class paint the graphs/plots, and instantiate this contro class with any subclass for each type of graph/plot that I want draw...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the correct thing to do

Answer (score 2):

Create your XIB as the container for the graph. It contains all of the common views and functionality, but not the graph specific content.

Now, when you load the NIB, you will always get a `BaseClass` instance. Indeed, you must always get a `BaseClass` - you can not change the class that is unarchived from the NIB.

Your graph views shouldn't be subclasses of `BaseClass`. Your graph view class that is appropriate to the current situation should then be instantiated and added as a subview of the container view, which is owned by the `BaseClass` (container) instance.

If the graph view needs to change the common button status then you should provide the graph view with a reference to the `BaseClass` instance when you add it as a subview.

Comment: Thanks Wain for your responses